# Navbar padding?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I can't seem to figure out how to remove this space to left of the image, as well as the small space in between the images on the right. I've tried various things, but nothing has worked. Here is the HTML for the nav:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>A Dog's Life</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<header>
    <img src="images/navimg.png" class="navbarimg">
    <a href="/index.html"><img src="images/banner.jpg" style="width:100%"></a>
</header>
<nav>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="/index.html"><img src="images/home-nav.png" alt="Home"></a></li>
    <li><a href="/about.html"><img src="images/about-nav.png" alt="About"></a></li>
    <li><a href="/services.html"><img src="images/services-nav.png" alt="Services"></a></li>
    <li><a href="/gallery.html"><img src="images/gallery-nav.png" alt="Gallery"></a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact.html"><img src="images/contact-nav.png" alt="Contact"></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And the CSS:

```
body { background-color: #abc67e;
      color: #666666;
      font-family:Tahoma; 
      height: 100%;
}     
header { background-color: #ffe4b5;
         color: #FFFFFF;
         font-family: Tahoma; 
         margin-bottom: 0;
         z-index: 2;
}

h1 { line-height: 200%;
     background-image: url(sunset.jpg);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: right;
     padding-left: 20px;
     height: 72px;
     margin-bottom: 0;
}
nav { font-weight: bold;
      background-color: #deb887; 
      z-index: 1;
}
h2 {  font-family: Tahoma; 
}
dt { color: #000033; 
     font-weight: bold;
}            
footer { font-size: 0.70em;
         text-align: center;
         font-style: italic;
         padding: 10px;
}        
h3 { color: #000033; 
}
main { padding-left: 20px;
      padding-right: 20px;
}
#wrapper { margin-left: auto;
           margin-right: auto;
           width: 55%;
           background-color: #fdf5e6;
           min-width: auto;
           box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #523411;
           height: 100%;
           border: 4px;
           border-style: outset;
}
nav ul { list-style-type: none; 
        margin-top: 0;
        z-index: 99;}
nav li { display: inline; }
footer ul { list-style-type: none; }
footer li { display: inline; }
footer a { text-decoration: none; padding-right: 10px; }
aside { float: right; 
      border-left: 1px;
      border-left-style: dotted;
      padding-left: 50px;}
aside img { width: 100%;
          height: 100%;}
section { float: right;
        width: 320px;}
.galleryul { list-style-type: none; }
.galleryli { display: inline-block;
     width: 225px;
     padding-bottom: 10px;
     margin: 10px;
     background-color: #EAEAEA;
     text-align: center;
     font-style: italic;
     font-family: Tahoma; }
label { float: left; 
      display: block; 
      width: 8em;
      padding-right: 25px; 
      }
input { display: block;
      margin-bottom: 1em;
      }
textarea { display: block; 
        margin-bottom: 1em;
      }
#mySubmit { margin-left: 11.5em;
      }
.navbarimg { position: absolute; 
             padding-left: 650px;
             padding-top: 110px;
            z-index: -1;}
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Martin like this? https://jsfiddle.net/e1Lv42fa/

Comment: Its your border on the wrapper, just remove the left border https://jsfiddle.net/e1Lv42fa/1/

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith that didn't work

Answer (score 1):

`<ul>` element has by default `padding-left`, so you need to remove it with:

```
nav ul {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Then the space between each image is because you have each `<li>` on a separate line and `<li>` has `display: inline` set, therefore browser adds a space between them. You can force it to make no spaces with `float: left`:

```
nav li { 
    float: left;
}
```

Now the `<ul>` wrapper needs to know that it should cover the entire content including floating elements so you can set it `overflow: auto`.

```
nav ul {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

See updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f1s11mxp/

Comment: Ah this did the trick. I did not know about ul having default padding and the spaces for <li>. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Add to your `nav ul` a `padding-left` of `0`:

```
nav ul {
  // other styles

  padding-left: 0;

  // other styles
}
```

And the trick I often have to resort to to get rid of space between inline or inline-block elements is to 'comment out' as it were the white space in the HTML markup like so:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/index.html"><img src="images/home-nav.png" alt="Home"></a></li><!--
        --><li><a href="/about.html"><img src="images/about-nav.png" alt="About"></a></li><!--
        --><li><a href="/services.html"><img src="images/services-nav.png" alt="Services"></a></li><!--
        --><li><a href="/gallery.html"><img src="images/gallery-nav.png" alt="Gallery"></a></li><!--
        --><li><a href="/contact.html"><img src="images/contact-nav.png" alt="Contact"></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```